# why is not (123 == 0123) in java?

Tags: java, integer, operators, equality-operator

I am developing an application in Android using Eclipse. I wrote the following code and in tests the first and third "**if**" block is not reachable. Why?

When I add a leading zero to a number, the equal operator returns false.

```
int var = 123;
if (var == 0123) {
    //not reachable
}
if (var == 123) {
    //reachable
}
if (var == (int)0123) {
    //not reachable
}
if (var == (int)123) {
    //reachable
}
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`0123` is an octal number ([leading 0](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1)), while `123` is a decimal number.

so 0123 actually equals to 83.

Comment: how can i set it as decimal number?

Answer (score 22):

> Any integer Number Leading With Zero is octal Number (base 8).

`0123` is octal Number and `123` is Decimal Number

```
 0123 = (3*8^0) +(2*8^1)+(1*8^2)+(0*8^4)
        =3+16+64+0
        =83
```

Answer (score 9):

because 0123 in not decimal digit its octal (base 8)
so this is equal to 83

To convert a number k to decimal, use the formula that defines its base-8 representation:

[image]

```
0123 base-8 = 83 decimal

0123 = (3*8^0) +(2*8^1)+(1*8^2)+(0*8^4)
     =3+16+64+0
     =83
```

> An octal numeral consists of an ASCII digit 0 followed by one or more of the ASCII digits 0 through 7 and can represent a positive, zero, or negative integer.

**Note:** Octal values are denoted in java by leading zero normal decimal number cannot have a leading zero