# Asp.net MVC data annotations treats 0123 as non integer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, integer, range, data-annotations

related: [why is not (123 == 0123) in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461490/is-not-123-0123-in-java)

For a phone number i am validating using MVC Data Annotations like below

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[\d]{3}$", ErrorMessage = "*")]
[Range(0, 999, ErrorMessage = "*")]
public int IntlCode { get; set; }
```

value `012` validates fine in Client side but does not on the server side, Could someone explain why or what is wrong

Comment: how are you setting this value?

Comment: @dove the above is a property of `User` ViewModel that my view binds to. User types in his international code which is 3 digit number and clicks submit. ActionMethod receives the ViewModel and then processes it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it is an `int` it is stripping the leading `0` which will cause your regex to fail

Try

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d{1,3}$", ErrorMessage = "*")]
```

Comment: So stripping `012` of `0` will yield `12` that's why it does not match regex right?