# Bitwise operation 111&011=9, how?

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

The bitwise operation 111&011 is giving output as **9** in java. 
how?
111&011 should be 011, i.e 3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why is not (123 == 0123) in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461490/why-is-not-123-0123-in-java)

Comment: you could try `0b111 & 0b011`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're specifying the numbers as decimal and *octal*, not as binary as you assume.

```
           number  | decimal value | binary  
           --------- -----------------------
(decimal)  111     | 111           | 1101111 
(octal)    011     | 9             | 0001001
```

so:

```
   1101111
&     1001
   -------
   0001001
```

and `1001 = 2^3 + 1 = 9`

to check it out use `Integer.toBinaryString`

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
  System.out.println(
    Integer.toBinaryString(111));

  System.out.println(
    Integer.toBinaryString(011));

  System.out.println(111 & 011);
}
```

code on [ideone](http://ideone.com/oZlIXk)

Comment: change the title of the table, or add another column - 011 is octal, not decimal (binary value is correct) {and this is NOT [boolean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boolean)}

Comment: but `111` is not octal either [:-)

Comment: the literal `111` is a decimal and has a value of 111. the literal `011` is octal and has a value of 9

Comment: indeed, it was a quick response, and I didn't get the table header quite right ^^", I hope the edit make it clearer

Answer (score 1):

Complementing yaitloutou's  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41907896/85421):  an integer literal can be represented in different bases in Java:

- `0`, just the digit zero (base does not matter, but specified as decimal)
- *decimal*: a non-zero decimal digit eventually followed by decimal digits, e.g. `20`
- *hexadecimal*: `0x` followed by one or more hexadecimal digits, e.g. `0x14`
- *octal*: `0` followed by one or more octal digits, e.g. `024`
- *binary*: `0b` followed by zeros and ones, e.g. `0b10100`

The underscore `_` can be used to separate digits, it will be ignored, e.g. `0b0001_0100`

See the [Java Language Specification 3.10.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1) for more details.